# grails/groovy: How do I access saved domain objects when unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, class, grails, groovy, dns

I'm trying to get access to saved domain objects during unit testing, so when a controller method saves a domain class outside the scope of the unit test i can access it to test the properties set on it.

have been looking at the domainClassesInfo (DefaultArtefactInfo), savedMetaClasses from interrogating this, but without success.

This seems like something that should be easy -

```
void testMyControllerMethod() {
  mockDomain(MyDomainClass)
  controller.myControllerMethod()
  //get MyDomainClass instance here for test assertions
  //assertEquals value1, myDomainClass.attribute1
}
```

then in the controller:

```
def MyControllerMethod() {
  //do stuff
  MyDomainClass myDomainClass = new MyDomainClass(attribute1:value1,attribute2:value2)
  myDomainClass.save()
}
```

Any thoughts how to extract the saved domain class much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF the controller is the only one saving a new instance of MyDomainClass then you should be able to do this:

```
void testMyControllerMethod() {
  mockDomain(MyDomainClass)
  controller.myControllerMethod()
  //get MyDomainClass instance here for test assertions
  def result = MyDomainClass.list()[0]

  assertEquals value1, result.attribute1      
}
```

Comment: Thank you MyDomainClass.list() worked an absolute treat and avoided needing complex workarounds and integration tests. Thank you very much